# INNER Join not returning all results

Tags: mysql

I'm saving in my MySQL DB the information added to a generated XML file. As sometimes there are errors, I have the "Version" column as counter (needed as it changes an ID in the XML).

When I try to select only the last version of each generated file, it's not returning every line. If the Version is 1, some of them are not returned. I changed manually the Version to 2 and the query returned it.

```
select tt.AssetID, tt.Provider, tt.FilmType, tt.EpSeaNumber, tt.OriginalTitle,
tt.Title, tt.Quality, tt.Audios, tt.Commercial, tt.TVODType, tt.Year, 
tt.Synopsis, tt.SynopsisMedium, tt.Actors, tt.Director, tt.Runtime, tt.Country,
 tt.Genre, tt.Rating, tt.StartDate, tt.EndDate 
FROM ingestions tt INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(Version) AS MaxVersion, GJLID FROM ingestions GROUP BY GJLID)
 groupedtt ON tt.GJLID = groupedtt.GJLID AND tt.Version = groupedtt.MaxVersion 
WHERE tt.Client = "TAR" and Synopsis <>""
```

Comment: Thats proper `INNER JOIN` behaviour. It will only return information which exactly matches the ON condition you specified. Try switching to LEFT JOIN

Comment: In both selects i'm pointing to the same table so there will be always exact matches.

Comment: Actually it will only return values from tt that which tt.GJLID = groupedtt.GJLID, if for example, there is a row tt.GJLID =1 and no groupedtt.GJLID = 1, it wont bring tt.GJLID= 1

Comment: In both selects i'm getting all the information, but in the groupedtt, i'm retrieving only the one with higer Version. So, the groupedtt will always exist in tt. My problem is that only sometimes and when the version is 1 is not retrieved...